# reCAPTCHA Displayed in a FORM - Image Needs Padding

Tags: php, css, forms, recaptcha

I've got a fully functional reCAPTCHA widget located [here](http://www.mynextbit.com/Pages/ArabicRootMachine/feedback.php).  It's part of a larger HTML FORM and I'm having difficulty adjusting the image that is returned from:

```
<?php echo recaptcha_get_html($public_key); ?>
```

Adding any padding/margin to the form itself moves everything to the right, but I only need to adjust the widget.  Does my answer lie with a CSS attribute that I can surround this PHP script with?

I'll show the entire form if it helps... Thank you in advance for any hints or solutions.

```
<form id="feedback" method="post" action="">
<p>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="formbox"
    <?php if ($missing || $errors) { 
          if(isset($name)){
            echo 'value="' . htmlentities($name, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '"'; 
          }
        } ?>>
    <?php if ($missing && in_array('name', $missing)) { ?> 
          <span class="warning"><font color="red">Please enter your name</font></span> 
    <?php } ?>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="formbox"/
    <?php if ($missing || $errors) { 
          if(isset($email)){
            echo 'value="' . htmlentities($email, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '"'; 
          }
        } ?>>
    <?php if ($missing && in_array('email', $missing)) { ?> 
            <span class="warning"><font color="red">Please enter your email address</font></span> 
    <?php } elseif (isset($errors['email'])) { ?> 
          <span class="warning"><font color="red">Invalid email address</font></span> 
        <?php } ?>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="comments">Comments:
    <?php if ($missing && in_array('comments', $missing)) { ?> 
            <span class="warning"><font color="red">Please enter your comments</font></span> 
    <?php } ?> 
    <br /></label>
    <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="60" rows="8"><?php 
          if ($missing || $errors) { 
            if(isset($comments)){
                echo htmlentities($comments, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); 
            }
          } ?></textarea>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var RecaptchaOptions = {
        theme : 'white'
    };
</script>
<?php 
//Display the error message if the values don't match.
if (isset($errors['recaptcha'])) { ?> 
    <p><font color="red">The values didn't match. Try again.</font></p>
<?php } ?>

<?php echo recaptcha_get_html($public_key); ?>
<p>
  <input name="send" id="send" type="submit" value="Send message" />
</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what you need..

**CSS**

```
#recaptcha_widget_div {
    margin-left: 18px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="recaptcha_widget_div">
    <?php echo recaptcha_get_html($public_key); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Josh, this worked fine - I thought I had tried this briefly, but I must have had some syntax issues.  Wrapped the php script in the div you defined and it lines up perfectly.  Thank you very much.